# Onmousedown attribute not detecting if the mouse is dragging?

Tags: javascript, html

It's Christmas time! So, I'm trying to make a snowman building game and I did:

```
<img onmousedown="build(event, this)" id="head" src="head.svg">
```

*"onmousedown" is where I got the error*

and for the JS I did:

```
const sm = {
    head: document.getElementById('head'),
    body: document.getElementById('body'),
    bottom: document.getElementById('bottom'),
    stick1: document.getElementById('stick1'),
    stick2: document.getElementById('stick2')
}

function build(event, smPart) {
    x = event.clientX
    y = event.clientY

    smPart.style.position = 'absolute'
    smPart.style.left = (x - (smPart.width / 2)).toString() + 'px'
    smPart.style.top = (y - (smPart.height / 2)).toString() + 'px'
}
```

Also "sm" stands for snowman.

Comment: what error you getting and what result you want? your question is not clear

Comment: Is the script being called before the img? Are you missing semi colons? Is there an error?

Comment: First, I have no error, but I just want the "onmousedown" attribute to work for dragging. Second, the script is called after the img and you don't need semicolons, but you can add them if it's your style. Like I said, there's no errors

Comment: If the "onmousedown" attribute doesn't work for dragging, then you can tell me if I need to use a different attribute.